# Is there a wsgi server that will do progressive Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Tags: python, wsgi

Is there a wsgi webserver that can do a progressive Transfer-Encoding: chunked? I.E. it should write the content to the socket as it is received from the application.

I tried the following app with wsgiref, waitress, and gunicorn. None of them write the `'First bit of content'` straight away..

```
import time

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    def content():
        yield 'First bit of content\n'
        time.sleep(5)
        yield 'Second bit of content'
    return content()
```

Comment: If by "None of them worked" you expect data to be immediately written to the socket -- it isn't. When there's enough data to be written to a socket, then it'll be written... not until then... (or the socket is otherwise flushed/closed)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I'll update the question. Are you saying that if I yield enough data, it will get written. How much is enough?

Comment: Yes - how much is enough is dependent on the server settings. Also, once it is transmitted to the browser, it's up to the browser to decide whether to display it, and what part of it to display (eg, it might ignore incomplete `tr` tags or something)... It sounds like you're potentially after websockets instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tips from Jon, I got it working in waitress:

```
import time


def app(environ, start_response):

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])

    def content():
        yield ''.join(('First bit of content', '.' * 18000, '\n'))
        time.sleep(5)
        yield 'Second bit of content'
    return content()

import waitress
waitress.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

waitress will send the data when it reaches 18000 bytes (which is also configurable when you create the server.)

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the WSGI specification, all WSGI servers should support this. This is because it is a requirement of the WSGI specification that a WSGI server flushes out data between each yield so that it is written back to the client, or otherwise ensures that the writing back of data to the client happens in parallel and is not buffered.